# Proper way to create an untextured, colored cube in XNA?

Tags: c#, xna, vertex-buffer, voxel

I'm currently trying to convert [this code](https://sites.google.com/site/letsmakeavoxelengine/home/display-lists-or-vertex-buffers) to C# XNA, however I'm having an issue with converting the CreateCube method - the resources on creating vertex lists in XNA seem to be outdated, dead, or just don't work.

Can anyone give me some help? I just want to create a colored, untextured cube by manually setting the vertexes of each face, then adding the (Those) cubes, or portions of cubes, to a VertexList to render.

Comment: What resources are you talking about? The general approach is the following: Create a vertex buffer with all your vertices (-> 8). Create an index buffer with all your triangles' indices (-> 36). I'm sure there are many resources about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this article on how to [Construct, Draw and Texture a cube](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dawate/archive/2011/01/20/constructing-drawing-and-texturing-a-cube-with-vertices-in-xna-on-windows-phone-7.aspx).  You can leave out the Texturing part as you don't require that, but the article is a good start and follows a similar approach to your article.